# How to populate an array with a ten digit number

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a program that asks a user for a ten digit number and then stores each digit in an array.

```
public class checksum {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int david[] = new int[10];
    System.out.println("Enter your 10 digit number: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < david.length; i++) {

        david[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println(david);

}
```

}

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Does `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(david));` help?

Comment: No! Thanks anyway got it sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read it as `String` and then populate array using `String.charAt`

```
    int david[] = new int[10];
    System.out.println("Enter your 10 digit number: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.next();
    if (str.length() < david.length) {
        System.out.println("invalid number");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < david.length; i++) {

        david[i] = Character.digit(str.charAt(i), 10);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(david));
```

Output:

```
Enter your 10 digit number: 
1234567890
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have put the read code inside the loop which will make the console wait for 10 inputs. You can take the input once and break the number then. Below is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int david[] = new int[10];
    System.out.println("Enter your 10 digit number: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i = david.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        david[i] = number%10;
        number /= 10;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < david.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(david[i]);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Modified the display logic, previously it was displaying array directly. Previously I didn't modify the display logic. Modified the post and made the amendments.